# UITableViewCell accessoryType set, but accessoryView is nil. How do I set the accessoryView backgroundColor?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

Here's how my cells are set up:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewIn cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"subcategory";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewIn dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[subcategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return cell;
}
```

As one can see, I set the background of the `contentView`, and that works just fine - but when I try to do the same thing with `backgroundView` or `accessoryView`, nothing happens because `backgroundView` and `accessoryView` both seem to be nil.

When one sets the `accessoryType` rather than the `accessoryView`, how does one then go about setting the background of the accessory?

Comment: Thanks for both answers.  It does seem rather obvious now: I just set `cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease]; cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];`, and all was fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [UITableViewCell Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

**backgroundView**

> **Discussion**
>
> The default is nil for cells in plain-style tables (UITableViewStylePlain) and non-nil for grouped-style tables UITableViewStyleGrouped). UITableViewCell adds the background view as a subview behind all other views and uses its current frame location.

**accessoryView**

> **Discussion**
>
> If the value of this property is not nil, the UITableViewCell class uses the given view for the accessory view in the table view’s normal (default) state; it ignores the value of the accessoryType  property. The provided accessory view can be a framework-provided control or label or a custom view. The accessory view appears in the the right side of the cell.

These views will be nil until you define them, and so you can set their backgrounds as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the reference from Apple:

`@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *accessoryView`

> If the value of this property is not
>   nil, the UITableViewCell class uses
>   the given view for the accessory view
>   in the table view’s normal (default)
>   state; it ignores the value of the
>   accessoryType property. The provided
>   accessory view can be a
>   framework-provided control or label or
>   a custom view. The accessory view
>   appears in the the right side of the
>   cell.

What I understand here is that if you set it, then the runtime will use it and ignore the `accessoryType`. But I suspect that the vice versa will be the same. I mean that if you set the `accessoryType`, then the value of the `accessoryView` will be still nil.

I think this is the design purpose. If you don't set the `accessoryView` but set the `accessoryType`, then the runtime has to decide what it has to do: If it sets the `accessoryView`, then the value of that property is not nil, then it has to ignore the `accessoryType`, which shouldn't be the case

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/85811)

```
let backgroundView = UIView()  
backgroundView.backgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor  
cell.backgroundView = backgroundView
```